# How to grep version of apache?

Tags: bash, apache, grep

I'm trying to create a script which checks updates for apache and some other web server stuff for custom web panel and I'm having hard time while grep'ing current installed version of apache.

I tried to use that command to grep version of apache but the output is not containing numbers.

My command:

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd  -v | grep  "version" | cut -d " " -f 3
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
Apache/2.4.46
```

And I need just 2.4.46 part of this thing.

BTW. There is the output of full **/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd  -v** command:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 20 2020 22:34:56
```

I'm not familiar with linux that's not my active job. I hope someone will figure it out for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'`:

```
$ /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -v grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
2.4.46
```

to match digits, full stop, digits, full stop, digits

Comment: Oh, I wasn't know.

BTW. I'm using that ugly code for grabing latest version. Do you have any idea about that too?
**curl -Ss "https://downloads.apache.org//httpd/" | grep CURRENT-IS- | cut -b 64-69**

Comment: You should ask a different question for that. This question was answered. I'll be happy to help you in a different question.

Comment: Okay. I'm new on stackoverflow. I'm learning. Thanks a lot!!!